# Adding series in a table and breaking again when the value reaches 230 to start again

Tags: excel

I'm working on a school project and maybe one of you can help me with the following excel problem. I tried to google a little bit but I can't properly formulate my question.

I have a table in excel that looks like this:

[image: A snippet of excel table]

I'd like to be able to sum contents in U column until the result reaches 235 and then start again from 0. Column B represents different days of the week. When a day changes, the calculations also should start from 0. Can anyone help?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Test if it will go over the amount or changes days,  If so start over, otherwias add to the running total.

```
=IF(OR(B2<>B1,SUM(V1,U2)>235),U2,SUM(V1,U2))
```

[image]